# Escaping wildcard file paths perl

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I have an array of files:

```
my @plistFiles = glob('Logs/*/*.plist');
```

which I need to escape, that will contain '(' and ')' as well as the usual spaces.

Here is one of the file paths @plistFiles will return:

```
Logs/Run 1 (13)/Automation Results.plist
```

I currently have this code for escaping spaces in file paths which I pass to a command in the Terminal in OSX:

```
$plistFile =~ s/\ /\\\ /g;
```

So how can I edit this regex to also escape ( and )?

Would this be correct just for escaping ( and )?:

```
$plistFile =~ s/\(\d)/\\\(\d\\\)/g;
```

Comment: With what do you want to replace "and" ?

Comment: @sputnick I dont want to "replace" but just escape the characters

Comment: what exactly do you want to 'escape' and for what purpose? All `(` and  `)`, or only those around numbers? Spaces also? other metacharacters?

Comment: @pavel Just `(`,`)` around numbers and all spaces, I am using each file path in Terminal so I need those chars escaped. There are no other metachars.

Comment: You didn't specify what you are escaping for, so how can we know what needs to be escaped or how to escape it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To convert e.g. `(13)` to `\(13\)`, you could write:

```
$plistFile =~ s/ /\\ /g;
$plistFile =~ s/\((\d+)\)/\\($1\\)/g;
```

But I think you're probably better off just escaping *all* instances of `(` and `)`, whether or not they surround numbers:

```
$plistFile =~ s/([ ()])/\\$1/g;
```

Comment: I am just trying to understand your last line of code, correct me if I am wrong but that means: any instance of `()` will be replaced with `\ \(\)`?

Comment: @user1160022: It means that any space, left-parenthesis, or right-parenthesis will be replaced with a backslash plus itself. (It uses the `[...]` notation for a [character-class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), the `(...)` notation for a [capture-group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and the special variable `$1` to retrieve the contents of the first capture-group.)

Comment: @Ωmega: It's not necessary, but using `$&` imposes a performance penalty on all regex-matches anywhere else in the entire program. That penalty is not usually worth losing sleep over, but in the context of a StackOverflow answer, when I don't even know what else the program is doing, I prefer to avoid it. Also, I think `$1` is slightly clearer than `$&`, in that (almost?) all Perl-like regex engines have adopted `$1`, but several major ones have not adopted `$&`. (By the way, a nitpick: properly speaking, a "backreference" would be if I'd used something like `\1` inside the pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why a call to `quotemeta` won't suffice. Yes it will also escape the slashes and dots, but that shouldn't matter.

However it is also simple to escape just whitespace and parentheses.

This program show both techniques

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $path = 'Logs/Run 1 (13)/Automation Results.plist';
my $escaped = quotemeta $path;
say $escaped;

$escaped = $path =~ s/([\s()])/\\$1/gr;
say $escaped;
```

**output**

```
Logs\/Run\ 1\ \(13\)\/Automation\ Results\.plist

Logs/Run\ 1\ \(13\)/Automation\ Results.plist
```

Comment: I am learning perl and didn't know about quotemeta, but I have had some experience with regex so I used this approach

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can add escape slashes with

```
s/[() ]/\\$&/g;
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/zRIyb5)**.

or

```
s/(?=[() ])/\\/g;
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/Dx6Xxl)**.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it easier to use {} to delimit your regex. Saves some \ eye wobbliness.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use 5.10.0;
use Data::Dumper;

my $to_match = "( this dreadful ) filename";
$to_match =~ s{([\(\)])}{\\$1}g;
say $to_match;
```

This does this:

```
$ perl x.pl
\( this dreadful \) filename
```

If you need to escape spaces as well as ()s then

```
$to_match =~ s{([\(\s\)])}{\\$1}g;
```

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't make sense to me. Using `s{}{}` instead of `s///` will only save backslashes if the pattern or replacement contains `/` -- which is not the case here.